# Term for a person/group of persons wanting to celebrate all

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example if in an organization only the day of work, Christmas and independence day are given official celebrations throughout the company. But then in the offices are people wanting to celebrate also father's day, mother's day, etc.

Is there a term for the creator(s)?

Comment: Party-loving colleagues ?

Answer (score 3):

*[Party animal](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Party%20Animal&defid=1108495)*:

> a person who loves parties
>   <sub>*Urban Dictionary*</sub>

*The folks at work are such **party animals** that sometimes it feels like we don't have permission to work.*

From *[Your Gut is Still Not Smarter Than Your Head](https://books.google.com/books?id=C1g9qyTTrvAC&pg=PA79&dq=%22party%20animals%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ogiKVa67Com1-AGL54HACQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=%22party%20animals%22&f=false)* by  Kevin Clancy and Peter Krieg:

> “*Party Animals*” spend the most while prowling, looking for a good
>   time;
>   “Fine Diners,” like “*Party Animals*,” do the bulk of the
>   drinking outside the home, but it's in white-tablecloth restaurants,
>   not bars and clubs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something a bit sarcastic, you might characterize them as *[cruise director](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruise_director)*

> a high-ranking or senior officer of a cruise ship with responsibility for all onboard hospitality, entertainment and social events

*Wikipedia*

Answer (score 0):

**Event Manager** with responsibility for corporate luncheons

Event management is the co-ordination, running and planning of all the people, teams and features that come together to create every kind of event.

Further information on a career in the field is available at:

[*Event Business Academy*](http://www.eventbusinessacademy.com);

[*Wikipedia*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_management)